# Replacing an element of a list with multiple values

Tags: python

if I have

```
l = ['a','b','x','f']
```

I want to replace `'x'` by `sub_list = ['c','d','e'`]

What is the best way to do this? I have,

```
l = l[:index_x] + sub_list + l[index_x+1:]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l = ['a','b','x','f']

sub_list = ['c','d','e']

ind = l.index("x")
l[ind:ind+1] = sub_list

print(l)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

If you have a list that has multiple `x's` using index will replace the first `x`.

If you wanted to replace all `x's`:

```
l = ['a','b','x','f',"x"]
sub_list = ['c','d','e']
for ind, ele in enumerate(l): # use l[:] if the element to be replaced is in sub_list
    if ele == "x":
        l[ind:ind+1] = sub_list
print(l)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Just as an aside: Your loop might run infinitely if the replacement contains the element to be replaced, e.g. if `sublist = ['c', 'x', 'e']`

Comment: @tobias_k, true, I added a comment to handle that case

Answer (score 2):

You can find the index of the element you wish to replace, then assign the sublist to a slice of the original list.

```
def replaceWithSublist(l, sub, elem):
    index = l.index(elem)
    l[index : index+1] = sub
    return l

>>> l = ['a','b','x','f']
>>> sublist = ['c','d','e']

>>> replaceWithSublist(l, sublist, 'x')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use the `insert()` method

```
l        = ['a','b','x','f']
sub_list = ['c','d','e']
ind      = l.index('x')

l.pop(ind)
for item in reversed(sub_list):
    l.insert(ind, item)
```